# How does NodeManager stop WebLogic on Linux

Tags: weblogic

Basic question about NodeManager and WebLogic. When I stop WebLogic from the admin console, NodeManager is used to stop WebLogic. How does it actually stop WebLogic ? Does it use kill -9 to kill the process ?
Also, how does it differentiate between a graceful shutdown and force shutdown ?

Answer (score 0):

The nodemanager triggers a server stop method in the Managed Server JVM process, which does a nice wind down of the Managed Server process.

The difference between a graceful and a forceful shutdown is that in case of a forceful shutdown the process gets indeed a kill -9 if it still alive by the end of the "Server lifecycle timeout" value (2 minutes by default).

Nice to know is that a graceful shutdown waits for user session to timeout, which may take a looooong time. You can disable this feature by dashing "Ignore sessions during shutdown" in the admin console under your server -> control -> start/stop.

Comment: I am trying to understand is the details on the stop process. Is this documented some place ?